# Deploying Multiple Grails Apps With Spring Security Against Same Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, grails, spring-security, grails-searchable

I have an existing Grails app which includes the Spring Security Core, Spring Security UI and Searchable plugins running on Tomcat against Oracle.

I have a new Grails app which will utilize the same plugins.  Both apps customize the Person (User) domain class with different fields.

When I tried to deploy the second app against the same Oracle Database as the existing app NONE of the Spring Security classes were created.  As a secondary issue there appears to be an issue with the Searchable plugin trying to create indexes.  Clearly an oversight on my part that trying to deploy this.

Does anyone have any experience with an issue like this?  Any workarounds you can think of?  The obvious choice to deploy the second app against a new instance of Oracle, but as you can imagine this is less than desirable.  My fall back plan is to merge the two applications, although this would be a great deal of work.  Any advice or thoughts would be appreciated.

Much Thanks

UPDATE:

Still unsure of why the second deployment did not work, I would up rolling both apps together in order to deploy.

Comment: "When I tried to deploy the second app against the same Oracle Database as the existing app NONE of the Spring Security classes were created". I didn't understand you. The Spring classes should be created by the `s2-quickstart` command, and not automatically. Also, it would be nice to see some stacktrace of the problems that you're having.

Comment: Hi Sergio thanks for the reply.  Yes the script created the classes in my app, but when I deploy the war to tomcat all domain classes are created except the Spring Security domain classes themselves (User, Role, UserRole, etc) presumably because they were created by the first app deployment.  I will update with the stacktrace shortly.

Comment: Are you attempting to deploy multiple apps that expect different table structures to the same Oracle schema?

Comment: yes, both the User classes I wish to deploy have some variance.  I am getting close to solving and will post the results.